# Regex - find text surrounded by double curly brackets ( `{{text}}` ) but not triple brackets ( '{{{text}}}' )

Tags: regex

I am parsing email content for `Handlebars.Net`. Use case is like so:

```
string template = "{{I should be found}} but {{{I shouldn't}}}";
```

I think I need to use some combination of lookaheads and lookbehinds to find these tags but I cannot get this to work. I've created a regex which is close to what I need but is not matching exactly like how I need to - `[^{]({{.*}})(!?})`

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: @anubhava this example is pcre (php) - I am using https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex with a negative lookaround assertions:

```
(?<!{){{[^{}]+}}(?!})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/w5b7Q7/2)

- `(?!})` is a negative lookahead assertion that fails the match if next character is `}`
- `(?<!{)` is a negative lookbehind assertion that fails the match if previous character is `{`